# Как вывести список в f строку?

Tags: python

Написал вот такой код. Не могу вывести список в f строку. Как это сделать?

```py
cust = []
first = input()
while first != 'Конец':
    cust.append(first)
    first = input()
year = input()
cust_year = []
for i in cust:
    stri = i.split(', ')
if stri[1] == year:
    cust_year.append(f'{stri[0]} (материал - {stri[2]})')
if len(cust_year) == 0:
    print(f'В этот год никто не покупал волшебные палочки.')
else:
    print(f'В {year} году волшебную палочку купили: {cust_year}')
```

[image: Задание]

Comment: ```{*cust_year}```

Comment: нужно звездочку убрать?

Comment: @Qwertiy если убрать звездочку, то будет вывод со скобками от списка. Как сделать, чтобы только содержимое списка вывелось? Не понимаю как в f строке сделать нормальный вывод списка. А в интернете не могу найти решение.

Comment: `{' '.join(cust_year)}`

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось

Comment: @Qwertiy не сработает такой вариант `{*cust_year}`. Вылезет ошибка: `can't use starred expression here`. Можно указать запятую в конце, но в строку добавятся лишние скобки, то есть вот так: `{*cust_year,}`. Вывод будет таким `'(2021,2022)'`. Использовать `join` оптимально здесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы вставляете в строку массив то он всегда будет выводиться с соответствующим форматом. Вы можете соединить все элементы из массива в одну цельную строку и вставить, например:

> gg = ['1', '2', '3']

```
''.join(gg)
'123'
```

в '' можно указать разделитель этих элементов:

```
','.join(gg)
'1,2,3'
```

Полученную строку уже можно спокойно вставить в другую строку без проблем.